# how to get started with TopCoder to update/develop algorithm skills?

Tags: algorithm

at workplace, the work I do is hardly near to challenging and doing that I think I might be losing the skills to look at a completely new problem and think about different ideas to solve it.

A friend suggested TopCoder.com to me, but looking at the overwhelming number of problems I can not decide how to get started?

what I want is to sharpen my techniques ( not particular language or framework ).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The only way to get started would be to pick problems.  Division I is the more difficult division, so you will probably find that the division I medium and hard problems will be somewhat interesting and challenging (unless you are quite clever.)

If you check the event calendar, you can see what algorithm competition rounds are coming up in your time zone.  The competitions have the added virtue of forcing you to read and analyze other people's code in the challenge phase, so even if you would just as soon practice without a clock, you may find them interesting.

Comment: how should I deal with the frustration when I start to blame myself for not being intelligent enough to see the solution of hard problems? (is practice the key for insight and intelligence? or its knack that some people have and some don't "what I am asking is, can it be developed, I consider myself average on math skills(maybe less)")

Comment: It's totally practice and it can completely be developed.  There are both general (ways to attack and clarify problems where it isn't clear how to begin) and specific (fundamental algorithmic ideas like dynamic programming, BFS & DFS, flow on graphs) strategies that you'll learn which change these problems from intractable to understandable.  TC has a big tutorials section, written by top arena coders, that will almost definitely help: http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=alg_index  If it's an important skill for you, just keep working on it and you will progress.

Comment: I know a few of the best coders there. They all advice solving 4-6 problems or spending at least two hours a day, if you want to go 1900.

Answer (score 12):

TopCoder algorithm contests are a way to develop your coding speed.  Solving any of the problems in the practice arena is difficult unless you already have knowledge of various algorithms.

The problems on [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) suffer from the same flaw.  You already have to know the algorithms to solve the problems in a reasonable time frame.

What I would suggest is to pick a project that you're interested in, and pursue it as you have time.  As an example, I'm currently learning how to work with the [open street map](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) tiles in an Eclipse rich client platform.

Comment: Clearly problem solving strategies vary and "a lot" is subjective, but I'd like to provide an opposing view here - I've done quite a number of Project Euler problems, and they rarely require a lot of pre-existing algorithmic knowledge.  The easier half of the problems on TopCoder also assume quite little foreknowledge.

Answer (score 5):

Try whit http://projecteuler.net Problems difficulty can be assumed by number of solvers.

I prefer this page, because it is language invariant and problems are really challenging

Answer (score 2):

You need the experience of solving 2 problems in any online judge (like http://www.spoj.com, http://www.lightoj.com, http://www.codeforces.com) in any programming language of your choice. That will give you an idea about how are your programs tested online.

Then you can follow this -> http://localboyfrommadurai.blogspot.in/2011/12/new-to-topcoder.html